# Open select dropdown using button click jquery

Tags: jquery

```html
<select id="selectid">
<option value="1">User1</option>
<option value="2">User2</option>
<option value="3">User3</option>
</select>
```

I have a select with 3 option .I have a requirement in which by button click i want to show the select dropdown .Is there any way to achieve this in all browser using jquery .Any help is appreciated

Comment: Show some example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask